# Certificate extensions - specific constraints

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I have question about extensions of certificate and what specific extension should I use in my situation.

The problem is following: I have a CA and I want that CA will issue certificate only for specific type of service. For example imagine application that can do 4 different type of actions (let's say action A, action B, C and D). For every action the application has to authenticate. Now suppose that some application want to do only action A and C. I want to issue a certificate for this app that specifies only this two type of actions and the app can not use this certificate to authenticate to do action D.

And it does not have to just applications. You can image users here.

I realise that I can solve this with 4 different type of CA for each type of service but this seems to be clumsy. I studied extensions of certificates but I didn't find some that fits my needs. And I also read about attributed certificates that could solve this situations but I also heard that they are not so common so I am not sure about them.

Do I have to use attributed certificates or do I miss some simple solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mostly two main ways, one of which using certificate extensions, and one of which being a bad idea. These two are the same...

**In a certificate**, you can encode "usages" as part of the [`Extended Key Usage`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12) extension. In your terminology, you would define some OIDs for actions A, B, C and D, and put only OIDs for A and C in the certificate.

**What is bad about it** is that your are conflating *authentication* and *authorization* into a certificate, and certificates are not good at authorization. To be clear:

- *Authentication* is about making sure who is calling. That's what certificates are for: they bind an *identity* to a *public key*, and the transport protocol (e.g. SSL) makes sure that the caller controls the private key corresponding to that public key.
- *Authorization* is about deciding what a given individual should be allowed to do. It normally takes place *after* authentication.

Certificates are not good at authorization tasks, for a variety of reasons, in particular because the only mechanism which can "cancel" a certificate is *revocation*, which is asynchronous (it can takes several hours or even days for a revocation to propagate through CRL) and all-or-nothing (you cannot revoke a certificate partially). In your situation, this would mean that if you want to lock out a specific application, the locking-out will take hours to be effective; and you cannot remove the right to do action C without removing the right to do action A. Similarly, if you want to grant a new access right to a client, you have to issue a new certificate, and send it to the client; if the client stores its certificates on a device (e.g. a smart card), this can raise usability issues (a basic PC can *use* smart cards out of the box, but *writing* into the smart card requires some specific software).

For these reasons, you really should use certificates for authentication only. In a client/server context, the certificate is used by the client to demonstrate its identity to the server, but the authorization is a decision which is purely server-side. There is no need for the authorization data to ever occur on the client side.

In a Microsoft / Active Directory world, authorization would be embodied by ACL and group memberships on the AD servers. The certificates are used to map the requester onto an account, but the rights granted to that account are maintained in the AD server, not in the certificate.

Comment: Well, that seems to be the answer. I really hoped to use certificate via some extension to do these authorized services but I worried it can't be elegantly done. Thanks for quick answer.